# Using media queries in

Tags: theme, magento2.2, less, media

I'm extending the blank theme and adding styles to an _extend.less file located in

```
/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Inside the file iv've got the following code

```
// common & mobile styles
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .header.panel > .header.links > li {
        margin: 0;
        a {
            color: @dark-grey;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding: 0 5px;
        }
        &:hover > a {
            color: @primary__color;
        }
    }
}

// Should be everything above the screen_m breakpoint (768px) - but still doesn't work
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .header.panel > .header.links > li {
        margin: 133px !important;
    }
}
```

My problem is that my desktop styles aren't being applied, I've tried a whole load of ways of getting this to work but nothing is working.

I tried wrapping them in a normal media query like this...

```
// desktop
@media all and (min-device-width : 768px) {
    .header.panel > .header.links > li {
        margin: 133px;
    }
}
```

Which loaded the styles in, but it was getting overridden by a style defined in...

```
/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction with this because I feel like I'm going round in circles.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following:

You forgot the `web` folder

In your theme `/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme` you puted this `/css/source/_extend.less`, but you must add a `/web` folder to `/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme` and in `/web` folder add this `/css/source/_extend.less`.

**The result is:**

```
/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Same here `/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme/Magento_Theme/css/source/_module.less`

**The result is:**

```
/app/design/frontend/neil/mytheme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
```

Run this commands per row:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento maintenance:enable
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento module:enable --all --clear-static-content
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile

rm -Rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/_requirejs

php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: Apologies for that, I do infact have the files within the web directory - a silly typo on my behalf there. Updated the question.
I'm in developer mode, so ran the static-content:deploy -f command but i still have the same problem.

Comment: I updated my response at the end

Comment: Just ran all these commands and now im getting white screen on both frontend & backend

Comment: White screen was because of permissions. But it seems like my _theme.less file is being ignored now for some reason - running the commands above changed a hell of a lot of things. I'm guessing a done of stuff was cached despite me running cache:flush multiple times and delting the normal directors in /pub & /var/view_preprocessed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong media query, you are using `max` which is for `max-width`. So your styling will only apply UP TO `@screen__m`.

Replace `max` with `min`.

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .header.panel > .header.links > li {
        margin: 133px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thanks for this - Your right that there's an issue with the media query.... But they're not making sense to me.. i'll update my question to show what results I get with difference media queries.

Comment: I've replaced max with min and it's still not working - something isn't right with my media queries

Comment: Have you ruled out Magento cache, browser cache, Varnish cache? A quick way to test if it's being cached is to add `body { background-color: blue !important;}` outside of any media query. If your BG isn't blue you know it's cached or isn't being compiled. Then you can go from there to resolve it.

Comment: The standard LESS media queries aren't easy to understand, I highly recommend using the Sass blank theme and Frontools by Snowdog Apps. It is much easier and faster to work with.

Comment: Yeh, I started changing the backround color while testing them out, Ive got something working as I want it to now.. I think it was related to caching. It's the first time Ive used magento and it's caching system absolutely boggles my mind. Especially whilst developing. I've played with the settings in admin and all that jazz but it still seems to do whatever it wants. My _theme.less file is being ignored now, gotta figure that out.